# scikitlearn - result from HTML code parsing

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Which ML model can be best used to learn to map between HTML code and resulting strings?
For example, if a model trains on 1000 websites containing various grids and names in different HTML code as input, which model is best used to output the names and image tags associated with the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach would be a Transformer. Transformers are currently the industry standard when it comes to NLP problems. There are many different Transformers on hugging face which you can find here: https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.9.2/quicktour.html

I am not sure if there is a pre-trained model for your specific use case but you will find a lot of information on this topic there.